# Why Sum() in Django returns number with 13 decimal places when evaluating numbers with only 2 decimal places?

Tags: django, django-views

I am learning Django and creating a cart application.
What I am trying to do here is to display on the HTML page the sum of all the cart items 'prices'.

Now, I know this is probably the worst way to do it, as I have seen many tutorials, but I'd rather learn step by step.

So what I am doing here is setting the variable 'total' equal to the sum of all prices using the `Sum()` function documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum).

The problem is that it displays a number with 13 decimal places, although my model allows just 2 decimal places. How can I overcome this issue?

Here is all the code, and obviously If you have any tip about a better 'basic' way to do this (a best practice) please let me know in the comments.

'models.py'

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order number: %s' % self.id
```

'views.py'

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart, Item
from django.db.models import Sum


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    carts = Cart.objects.all()
    length = len(Cart.objects.all())
    cart = carts[length - 1]
    cart_items = cart.items.all()
    total = cart_items.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
    return render(request, 'cart/home.html', {'cart': cart,
                                              'items': items,
                                              'cart_items': cart_items,
                                              'total': total})
```

and my 'home.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1>Menu</h1></div>
{% for item in items %}
<ul>{{ item }} £{{ item.price}} <button>Add</button></ul>
{% endfor %}
<div><h1>Order</h1></div>
{{ cart }}
{% for item in cart_items %}
    <ul>{{ item.name }} {{ item.price }}</ul>
{% endfor %}
<h2>Total</h2>
{{ total }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQLite 3 ...

Comment: As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#decimal-handling) SQLite does not internally support decimal, therefore your sum returns a float. Just round it to 2 decimals using standard python float formatting. (You can also use the `floatformat` template filter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SQLite, you should know that it doesn't support decimal internally, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/databases/#decimal-handling). That's why `Sum()` returns a `float`.

You should therefore either use python float formatting functions to round `total` to 2 decimals or you can use the [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) template filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the total to a string and then send that to your HTML page in the context.

```
total = cart_items.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
total = '{:0.2f}'.format(total)
```

or if you want it formatted as a string with the dollar symbol and to add commas (for thousands of dollars):

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
...
total = cart_items.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
total = f"${intcomma('{:0.2f}'.format(total))}"
```

Comment: what could you do if the `aggregate` returns None (if there were no records). This `'{:0.2f}'.format(total)` fails then